# What Can I Do If My App Is Rejected Because the Update Check API (checkAppUpdate) Is Not Called?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

After my app is submitted for review, it is rejected by Huawei due to the **checkAppUpdate** API not having been called.
But I have checked my code, the **checkAppUpdate** API has been called indeed. Who can tell me how can I figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check whether the `checkAppUpdate` API has been called, by referring to the following documents:

   https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-game-update?ha_source=hms1

   https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update?ha_source=hms1
2. Check whether the obfuscation file configuration meets the document requirements.

   Reference:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001050260710-V5?ha_source=hms1
3. You are advised not to perform operations such as secondary encapsulation, hardening, and log output restriction on the APK submitted for review.
4. Set `debuggable` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to `true` during APK packaging.
5. Record the keyword **UpdateSDK version is: xxx** in logs if log filter is required. When an app is under review, this keyword is checked to determine whether the `checkAppUpdate` API is called.

   For Details,check:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-test?ha_source=hms1